# Always open with check is getting ignored

Tags: macos

I'm running into troubles with my mac 10.9.4 because I'm unable to assign default programs for certain file types.

In my example I'm trying to assign .xml files to always be opened with TextEdit. But no matter how often I check that "Always open with" checkbox it will always be ignored. XML-files remain to be opened with Safari no matter what I can do.

I'm pretty new to mac so I have no clue where to look for help regarding this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if you've tried this:-

Right click on an XML file and select `Get Info`

find the `Open With` section and choose TextEdit.

Underneath you should find an option for `Change All`

Clicking on that should change all XML files to open with TextEdit.

Comment: This appears to have done the trick, thanks a great deal mate!